# 'Cannot convert from _Ty2 to T*' error' with map

Tags: c++, pointers, interface

I want to return an element from a std::map as a pointer, but I keep getting this error and can't find a way to solve it.

The second element of map is a pointer to a IService, and the return of getService is a pointer to T, which is an IService, so I don't get why I get this error.

```cpp
// Locator.h
template <class T>
class Locator
{
public:
    static T* getService(ServiceType serviceType);
    static void provide(ServiceType serviceType, T* service);

private:
    static std::unordered_map<ServiceType, IService*> _services;
};
```

```cpp
// Locator.cpp
template <class T>
T* Locator<T>::getService(ServiceType serviceType)
{
    for (auto itr = _services.find(serviceType); itr != _services.end(); itr++)
    {
        return itr->second;
    }
}
```

```cpp
//IService.h
class IService
{
public:
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]: `T` is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: Unrelated, but the `for` loop looks *weird.* There's no looping at all, why are you using a loop?

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, it half-makes-sense if `T` is a class derived from `IService`. Which I assume this is what is attempted here, in which case `dynamic_cast<T*>` should solve it.

Comment: `getService` also has undefined behavior if `serviceType` is not a key of `_services`, and I'm quite sure the compiler really wants to warn you about that.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I would agree with you, so I do.

Comment: Since you already have one map for each `T`, you might as well put `T*` in your map instead. I suspect that this particular feature is not what you had in mind, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The for loop makes no sense -- the first match will break it and return.
2. There is a cast missing for the return value -- the map contains IService pointers which are unrelated to the return Type T*, except T* is a base of IService (but does not look like taht is intended). A dynamic cast can solve it in case of IService is a polymorphic type and the contained map elements support the cast to T*.

So try that:

```
template <class T>
T* Locator<T>::getService(ServiceType serviceType)
{
  auto itr = _services.find(serviceType);
  return itr != _services.end() ? dynamic_cast<T*>(itr->second) : nullptr;
}
```

And don't forget to add the variable for the static map (somewhere in the cpp):

```
std::unordered_map<ServiceType, IService*> Locator<ServiceImpl>::_services;
```

Comment: I don't get the second part of your answer with the variable for the static map. Why should I do that? What should be ServiceImpl ?
Thanks for the first part, the dynamic cast solved the problem! But now I have a link error, and I think it's related to the second part of your answer

Comment: You are right .. that needs a little bit more explanation. Static functions can only access static members ..  so the static member "_services" must be defined for each different type T somewhere in the CPP code (otherwise an "unresolved external" error will be reported from the linker. If you you use a `Locator<T>` with `T = ServiceImpl` you will need the definition of the map as given in the sample in the CPP code.